# dividing two variables in javascript

Tags: javascript

ok, so I am trying to make a midpoint calculator in JavaScript for fun and to practice with the language, The formula is pretty simple, it is just x1 + x2 / 2 and y1 + y2 / 2, I want the user to be able to define the x and y coordinates, and this is what I have come up with:

```
alert("welcome to nate's midpoint calculator!");
var x1 = prompt("type your first x coordanate!");
var y1 = prompt("excelent!, now your first y coordanate!");
var x2 = prompt("now type your second x coordanate!");
var y2 = prompt("and finally, your last y coordanate!");
var midText = ("your midpoints are: ");
var comma = (",");
var exclam = ("!");
var two = (2)
var x1x2 = (x1 + x2 / two);
var y1y2 = (y2 + y2 / two );
alert(midText + x1x2 + comma + y1y2 + exclam);
```

for some reason, this is not calculating correctly and turning in wrong answers, go ahead and [try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/L5mHE/). it may be some weird misstype from me, I am fairly new to javascript, only having worked with the language for an hour or two. any help would be very much appreciated! thanks in advance!

Comment: `go ahead and try it out` seriously ?

Comment: [ORDER OF OPERATIONS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)

Comment: here's a helpful video that contains an explanation of how to perform calculations given JavaScript's shortcomings -

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2ifWcnQs6M

Comment: @b_dubb just out of curiosity, what would those shortcomings be? Based on your math above and the order of operations, the equation will evaluate to `x2 / two + x1`. If that is what you're wanting great. I'm guessing however that you are aiming more for `(x1 + x2) / two`.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/28985/common-mistakes-with-javascript-arithmetic
this explains what i meant better than i ever could

Comment: @user2744763: As others said, you probably have TWO different problems: 1) Order of operations: (x1 + y2 / 2) <> ((x1 + y1)/2), and 2) string vs. numeric types (i.e. the need to use "+x" or "parseInt(x)".  Q: What did you find?  Did you resolve the problem?  Could you upvote and accept an answer?

Answer (score 7):

```
(x1 + x2 / two)
```

is dividing then concatenating a string and a number.
Try

```
((+x1 + +x2) / two)
```

which uses the prefix `+` operator to coerce strings to numbers and parenthesizes the low-precedence addition.

You can see this in action by doing

```
alert(("1" + "0") / 2)  // alerts 5 since "1" + "0" == "10"
alert((1 + 0) / 2)      // alerts 0.5 since 1 + 0 == 1
```

Comment: you're still going to have an order of operations problem.

Comment: +1 this is likely the correct answer...however division is still happening before the addition which is wrong.

Comment: nice! that works for me! the I missed the + in front of the variables. can you tell me why my post is getting downvoted? or even better, why there is an "upvote": and "downvote" mechanic at all? I think all questions are valid, even if they are what some people might think are "stupid" or "uneducated," Just remember all, you where all beginners once.

Comment: Relevant to at least half the question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: they are sometimes downvoted by someone who think they know better

Comment: @user2744763 the upvote/downvote mechanism is to help maintain a standard of quality. SO is not a complete free-for-all; read the FAQ.

Answer (score 4):

perhaps you need

```
var x1x2 = (parseInt(x1) + parseInt(x2)) / two;
var y1y2 = (parseInt(y2) + parseInt(y2)) / two;
```

Comment: what if they are floats?

Comment: sorry, I did not mean to write a complete solution in an answer, just a sample code to give an idea of how I would approach it

Answer (score 3):

### [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/L5mHE/1/)

**JS**

```
alert("welcome to nate's midpoint calculator!");
var x1 = prompt("type your first x coordanate!");
var y1 = prompt("excellent!, now your first y coordanate!");
var x2 = prompt("now type your second x coordanate!");
var y2 = prompt("and finally, your last y coordanate!");
var midText = ("your midpoints are: ");

var x1x2 = (+x1 + +x2) / 2;
var y1y2 = (+y2 + +y2) / 2 ;
alert(midText + x1x2 + "," + y1y2 + "!");
```

---

### [The way I would do it (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/L5mHE/5/)

**HTML**

```
<h1>Welcome to Nate's midpoint calculator!</h1>
<form>
    <div>
        <label for="x1">X1</label>
        <input type="textbox" id="x1" />
        <label for="y1">Y1</label>
        <input type="textbox" id="y1" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="x2">X2</label>
        <input type="textbox" id="x2" />
        <label for="y2">Y2</label>
        <input type="textbox" id="y2" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="Calculate()"/>
    </div>
</form>
<div>
    <span id="results"></span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function Calculate(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var x1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('x1').value);
    var y1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('y1').value);
    var x2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('x2').value);
    var y2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('y2').value);

    var x1x2 = parseFloat((x1 + +x2) / 2);
    var y1y2 = parseFloat((+y2 + +y2) / 2);
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=("your midpoints are: " + x1x2 + "," + y1y2 + "!");
}
```

---

### [Using KnockoutJS](http://jsfiddle.net/L5mHE/6/)

**HTML**

```
<h1>Welcome to Nate's midpoint calculator!</h1>

<div>
    <label for="x1">X1</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="x1" data-bind="value: x1" />
    <label for="y1">Y1</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="y1" data-bind="value: y1" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="x2">X2</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="x2" data-bind="value: x2" />
    <label for="y2">Y2</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="y2" data-bind="value: y2" />
</div>
<div> 
    your midpoints are: <span id="results" data-bind="text: Midpoint"></span>!
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var MidpointCalulatorViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.x1 = ko.observable();
    self.x2 = ko.observable();
    self.y1 = ko.observable();
    self.y2 = ko.observable();

    self.x1x2 = ko.computed(function () {
        return parseFloat((parseFloat(self.x1()) + parseFloat(self.x2())) / 2);
    }, self);

    self.y1y2 = ko.computed(function () {
        return parseFloat((parseFloat(self.y1()) + parseFloat(self.y2())) / 2);
    }, self);

    self.Midpoint = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.x1x2() + "," + self.y1y2();
    }, self);
};

ko.applyBindings(new MidpointCalulatorViewModel());
```

***Note you need validation***

Comment: this is even easier in angular. :)

Comment: no joke.. or backbone, knockout, or anything that is built for automatic DOM event handling and editting... :)

Comment: @akonsu angular = amazing. I wish I could +1000 your comment.